# Quick top level server language question

Tags: java, php, mono

Right, so if you have to decide on a server-side language for a distributed Linux-based server backend, would you choose:

1. PHP
2. Mono ASP.net
3. Java
4. Python (I've just added this because Google use it)

As a C++ programmer, I'm thinking Java+Tomcat, but I'd love to hear experienced thoughts here, especially relating to debugging and IDE (likely Eclipse).

Also, please, it's not a flame question.  I'm seeing excellent sites written in all, I'm just thinking about the compile/debug/release cycle.

I'm effectively receiving some HTTP request, and performing a reasonably sophisticated server-side function in response.  Sort of like a distributed, stateless RPC/REST system.

Cheers,

Shane

Comment: All else being equal, no, I wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

As a PHP programmer with some Java experience I don't recommend PHP. It's a powerful technology but it's full of rubbish and **personally** each day I hate it more and more.

I also vote for Java.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Java on [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/), as long as you stick to the Servlet standards, then switching the servlet container between Tomcat and Jetty should be fairly straight forward.

Have a look at [restlet](http://www.restlet.org/) for rest support.

From the way things appear to me lately, you'll probably want to look at a Dependency Injection framework, so look at either [spring](http://www.springsource.org/) or [guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/).

Logging frameworks ... probably [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/).

Build scripts ... I like [maven](http://maven.apache.org/), but its not everyone's first choice.
The learning curve can be a bit steep, although there may be some very useful [archetypes](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List), that can be used to set up an initial skeleton project structure.

You could use a maven archetype and then switch to using an [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) build script.
If you choose not to use maven, I would encourage you to at least adopt the [maven-style directory structure](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) for your project layout.

Hmmm, having said all of that I wouldn't blame you for wondering how bad it could be to just do it the old way, like we used to with apache httpd and cgi scripts in C or perl.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Since I've heard a couple of people mention it, I'm actually beginning to consider CGI + C++.  It would be nice to stay in my language of choice.  On the other hand, I don't want to buck the trend, and since I can program well in Java, and Google App Engine/GWT is also Java, it might be a good on-ramp for me to start with Jetty+Java, as you say.  Decisions, decisions...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would jump to a new language for this. There are C++ libraries for writing server components and extensions. You might as well leverage your existing expertise.

Obviously, the details of the project may make that impractical, were we to know them.

Comment: Really? I was unaware of this, can you please give me a popular example?

Comment: C++/CGI is mentioned elsewhere in this thread, which is a good answer. But, I was primarily thinking of writing a module in the Apache C++ standard library.

Comment: Ok, cool, that's right in line with what I want to do.  I'll look into it.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I would only have to choose between:

- Java - Probably with a simple servlet to deal all the requests (supposing it is a small external API)
- Mono - Using Monorail (maybe ASP.NET MVC) supposing you don't need to expose SOAP web services

The troubling part is that you are not clear about if your server is also distributed (if your backend would be running in many servers at the same time), as that would mean some additional constraints that would narrow the language/technology choice, perhaps pointing to outside your initial list.

Comment: Oh, I should have said, it's definitely distributed.  That's all I think about. :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm a C# developer, and I don't think Mono is a great idea. Can be buggy sometimes.

When it comer to Linux, best go with "open" comunnity.

I vote for java

Comment: That's a shame.  I would have thought because Mono ASP.net would be pretty solid, since it's open source and Novel backed...